# Symfony 4.2 DateTimeImmutable validator error

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, symfony-forms, php-7.2

I'm using Symfony 4.2.11 on PHP 7.2 with this code:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\LessThan;

class FormType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('startDate', DateType::class, [
            "required" => true,
            'input' => 'datetime_immutable',
            /*'constraints' => [
                new LessThan([
                    'propertyPath' => 'parent.all[endDate].data'
                ]),
            ]*/
        ]);
        $builder->add('endDate', DateType::class, [
            "required" => true,
            'input' => 'datetime_immutable',

    }
}


$form = $this->formFactory->create(FormType::class);
//$form->submit($formData);
$form->submit([
    "startDate" => new \DateTimeImmutable(),
    "endDate" => new \DateTimeImmutable()
]);
if (!$form->isValid()) {
    echo("Form invalid");
}
```

However when I run this code it prints out "Form Invalid". How do I fix this code so it accepts all `DateTimeImmutable` objects?

Comment: Can you explain why you are trying to submit `DateTimeImmutable` instances? Form submission is usually meant to handle an HTTP request which only consists of scalar or array data but not objects.

Comment: @xabbuh The input is being formatted upstream. Either way, the default for DateTimeType input is "datetime" which expects a DateTime object as input.

Comment: You are confusing the different data formats here. The Form component distinguishes three different formats. There is the model data which represents the data you are acting with in your application (i.e. `DateTime` objects). Then there is the view data which is the format used to present the data to the user (usually in the HTML). The norm data is the intermediate format. When your model is bound to the form, it's transformed to the norm and from there to the view data. On form submission data must be in the view format and will then be reverse transformed.

Comment: @xabbuh In that case what am I supposed to be passing into `submit()`? String dates ("2018-12-23T00:00:00") results in the same error.

Comment: If not configured differently, the format expected by default is an array with `year`, `month` and `day` fields: `$form->submit(['year' => '2018', 'month' => '12', 'day' => '23']);`

Comment: @xabbuh Replacing `new \DateTimeImmutable()` with that array results in "This form should not contain extra fields.".

Comment: Did you adapt the example to your actual form type structure to reflect that you have `startDate` and `endDate` subforms? It should look something like this: `$form->submit(['startDate' => ['year' => '2018', 'month' => '12', 'day' => '23'], 'endDate' => ['year' => '2018', 'month' => '12', 'day' => '23']]);`